# Find Construtor with attribute using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have code that looks for a constructor with a certain attribute like this:

```
...
ConstructorInfo ctor;
var ctors = valueType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors;
foreach (var ictor in ctors) {
    foreach (object attr in ictor.GetCustomAttributes(false)) {
        if (attr is MyConstructor) {
            ctor = ictor;
            goto Found;
        }
    }
}
throw new Exception($"Unable to find appropriate Constructor.");
Found:

... // do something with ctor
```

(OMG goto!)

My question is - can this be done better with Linq ? if yes how ?

Comment: Looks trivial, what did you try, where are you stuck? Do you get any errors?

Comment: tried ctors.SelectMany(ctor => ctor.GetCustomAttributes(false)).Where(o => o is MyConstructor); but then I loose the ctor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a try

```js
var ctors = valueType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors;
ConstructorInfo ctor = ctors.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(a=> a is MyConstructor));

if (ctor != null)
   goto Found;
```

Comment: .Any returns true of false. .FirstorDefault on .Any won't compile.

Comment: sorry its `FirstOrDefault` i updated it. And yah any check if it has an attribute it will return true or false